# How to setup multiple ssh identities for single hg repository?

Tags: mercurial, ssh, public-key

I am using ssh publickey authentication for my mercurial repository.  So I have:

```
[ui]
ssh = ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -C
```

in my .hgrc.  This works fine and allows me to push/pull to an ssh-authenticated repo.  However, I want to be able to push/pull to another repo that requires a different identity.  How can I configure my .hgrc file so the identity is tied to a particular path.  I guess I'd want something like:

```
[ui]
one.prefix = someserver.com
one.ssh = ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -C
two.prefix = otherserver.com
two.ssh = ssh -i ~/.ssh/otherid_rsa -C
```

Answer (score 8):

In your `~/.ssh/config`, add

```
Host someserver.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host otherserver.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/otherid_rsa
```

and anybody (including `hg` and interactive use) using `ssh` to connect to hosts `someserver.com` or `otherserver.com` will use the specified identity files.

See [`ssh_config`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5) for other options.

Answer (score 3):

You do it using ssh's own tool: ssh-agent.

```
$ eval $(ssh-agent)
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/otherid_rsa
```

Then you don't need ssh identify related anything in your `.hgrc`'s `[ui]` section at all.

Alternately you could do:

```
[ui]
ssh = ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -i ~/.ssh/otherid_rsa -C
```

but ssh-agent is useful in so many way's it's worth putting it your login scripts and calling it a day.

Comment: I think it is `ssh = ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -i ~/.ssh/otherid_rsa -C` otherwise we get an ssh usage error.