# Can't SSH to BitBucket with Mercurial with different identities

Tags: ssh, mercurial, bitbucket

So I just set up a second account on Bitbucket, and I'm using it with mercurial, just like the first one. I've followed the instructions [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-multiple-ssh-identities-for-gitbash-mac-osx-linux-271943168.html), and so my `~/.ssh/config` file looks like this:

```
 UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
 StrictHostKeyChecking no
 ForwardAgent yes

Host bitbucket.org
 HostName bitbucket.org
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host bitbucket.org
 HostName bitbucket.org
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal
```

Now, I can only SSH with the first identity on the file, and for the second I get:

```
remote: conq: repository access denied.
abort: no suitable response from remote
```

If I switch the two identities on the `config` file, then i can access using the one I couldn't before, and vice-versa. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup multiple ssh identities for single hg repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833289/how-to-setup-multiple-ssh-identities-for-single-hg-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the host alias names in `.ssh/config`:

**.ssh/config**

```
Host bitbucket1
 HostName bitbucket.org
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host bitbucket2
 HostName bitbucket.org
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal
```

**Usage**

```
# will use the ~/.ssh/id_rsa identity
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket1/your/repository

# will use the ~/.ssh/personal identity
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket2/your/repository
```

You can use any ssh aliases, the only important thing is that they be different for different identities. So you can preserve `Host bitbucket.org` for your first entry, and change the other one to `Host personal.bitbucket.org`.